# How to call .NET code in HTML5?

Tags: html

My client have an application built on Flex and .NET technologies. Flex calls the .NET code through the Flex Florine service. I need to to convert this application into HTML5. For this task, how do I call .NET code in HTML5?

Comment: You have DLL install with your application?

Comment: Yes..I've a data layer DLL built in c#.

Comment: HTML5 is not a programming language and cannot "call" anything. Since .NET stuff is Windows only, there is no interface for it. Obviously, there needs to be some other plug-in to do such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

My first advice to you is to learn about the "Holy Trinity" - HTML5, CSS & JavaScript,
If you want to load your own dll you have some options:

1. Create your DLL as COM  - read about it at http://p2p.wrox.com/javascript/17313-how-call-dll-method-javascritp-urgent.html
2. Use WPF browser or Silverlight to build xbap or xap file that you can implement in your web site.
3. Use WCF or web service to expose your dll, so your web site could make http requests.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with Flex Florine, but in HTML5, you use JavaScript — specifically, [`XMLHTTPRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) — to communicate with the server.